# update batch is not working in odbc connection in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc

I need to insert and update batch in odbc connection in codeigniter, but when i use update_batch function it gives me error `Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::_update_batch()` , can anyone please help me how can i resolve this error in codeigniter, it seems like odbc driver is not supported this function.

I am using this function 
ODBC Driver :

```
   $otherdb->update_batch('tb_target', $update_array, 'id');
```

Mysql Driver :

```
$this->db->update_batch('tb_target', $update_array, 'id');
```

It is working for mysql driver but not working with odbc driver

Comment: $otherdb->update_batch('tb_target', $update_array, 'id');

Comment: what's your CI version? see some change log of update_batch() here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html#bug-fixes-for-3-1-3 (and below)